# Can't create a custom User model in django

Tags: python, django

I have a custom passwordless user model built in django 1.11. user model looks like this

```
class User(models.Model):
    email = models.EmailField(primary_key=True)
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    is_anonymous = False
    is_authenticated = True
```

It's a custom user model and depends on a custom auth backend, given like this

```
class PasswordlessAuthenticationBackend():
    def authenticate(self, uid):
        try:
            token = Token.objects.get(uid=uid)
            return User.objects.get(email=token.email)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return User.objects.create(email=token.email)
        except Token.DoesNotExist:
            return None

    def get_user(self, email):
        try:
            return User.objects.get(email=email)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return None
```

The auth is registered and working fine. The token is just this

```
class Token(models.Model):
    email = models.EmailField()
    uid = models.CharField(default=uuid.uuid4, max_length=40)
```

The problem is, when I try to call `auth.login` in my `TestCase`, it always throws this error:

```
ValueError: The following fields do not exist in this model or are m2m fields: last_login
```

What are m2m fields? How and where do I specify this `last_login`?

Edit:

The failing test looks like this:

```
from django.test import TestCase
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.contrib import auth
from accounts.models import Token

User = get_user_model()
email = 'test@testing.com'

class UserModelTestcase(TestCase):
    def test_user_is_valid_with_email_only(self):
        user = User(email=email)
        user.full_clean()
    
    def test_email_is_primary_key(self):
        user = User(email=email)
        self.assertEqual(user.pk,email)

    def test_links_user_with_auto_generated_uid(self):
        token1 = Token.objects.create(email=email)
        token2 = Token.objects.create(email=email)
        self.assertNotEqual(token1.uid, token2.uid)
    
    def test_no_problem_with_auth_login(self):
        user = User.objects.create(email=email)
        user.backend = ''
        request = self.client.request().wsgi_request
        auth.login(request, user) #should not raise, fails!
```

Comment: Can you add you test as wel?

Comment: Do you get the correct User Model with get_user_model() or does that point to the Abstract User model?

Comment: This will solve your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38156681/error-about-django-custom-authentication-and-login  check the accepted answer

Comment: Sure, its just the normal `<class 'accounts.models.User'>`. a concrete class.

Comment: Thanks. Consider adding that as an answer and cite the sources. I'll be happy to accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this link [Error about Django custom authentication and login?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38156681/error-about-django-custom-authentication-and-login)

has an in-depth explanation about your problem an has multiple solutions you can pick.